# Why does my indicator-weather sometimes turn gray?

Tags: 11.04, indicator

I am on ubuntu natty unity. I am facing a problem regarding indicator-weather indicator applet. Sometimes, it does not work correctly and turns gray. Please see following image[image: Weather indicator turning gray]

If I click on refresh option then it works fine for 10-20 seconds and then again turns gray. For example, after refresh it will work for 10 seconds as shown in following image.[image]

I am using "Weather Indicator 11.05.31 'Cloudy 8'" version of indicator-weather and I am using https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator PPA to install this software.
Any pointers to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using any particular set of icons?  And if you change them (right-click on desktop, choose "Change Desktop Background," select the "Theme" tab, click the "Customize..." button, select the "Icons" tab), is there a change in the indicator?

Comment: This is not really a question for askubuntu and instead should be reported to the developers as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator

Answer (score 2):

That icon is displayed by Weather Indicator when an unknown weather condition is reported by the service. In other words it shows up when the icon theme has no icon representing the current weather.

The weather condition is what shows up on the second line of weather report:

[image: weather report]